# Does Cascading 3.0 Support Java 8?

Tags: java, cascading

I started exploring `Cascading` framework for some big data work.

Can i use `Java 8` to implement Cascading jobs?

Comment: Thanks so much for the Down Vote.. always welcome!!

Comment: Try doing a google search first then ask such general questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had asked this question, I therefore feel its quite imperative that your query gets answered. Yes, Cascading 3.0.4 can be used with jdk1.8.0_66 that means you can easily use cascading local mode in your windows system with a 64-bit JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE with java developer kit <=1.8. You may not be able to use lambda since every framework has its own limitations, so does cascading.
Hope my answer does suffice you.
Please comment the reason if you think the answer is not needed!